# Convert JQuery QR Code to Image using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, qr-code

I was wondering how it's possible to download the JQuery generated QR code or convert to a downloadable image (png/jpeg) using javascript.

I tried what was here:
[Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)
But no success. I think it's related to the output. There is a table and canvas output, but both do not give the image data...

Here is my code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/qrcode.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#output').qrcode("http://");
})


var canvas = document.getElementById("output");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
</script>
```

Also I was hoping to surround the QR Code with a white background (Adding rows and columns within the div) before converting to image to aid the detection (so that the background is also included in the image).

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: what do you mean by **download** or **downloadable**?

Comment: It seems that lines with `document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');` may get executed earlier than `jQuery('#output').qrcode("http://");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with this is that you called the toDataURL() function not for the canvas element.
You can get the canvas with jquery and it will work.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26297520)

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#output').qrcode("http://");

    var canvas = $('#output canvas');
    console.log(canvas);
    var img = canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");
    //or
    //var img = $(canvas)[0].toDataURL("image/png");
    document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
});
```

Comment: How can I add a filename? When I save it's 'untiltled'. I tried adding attributes but there is no output.

Comment: tried this
    var path = img.substring(0,img.lastindexOf('/')); // get the path 
    var fileName = img.substring(img.lastindexOf('/')); // and filename
    var newsrc = path+"/output"+"image.png"; // re-assemble   
    img.attr("src",newsrc);

Comment: If you want a filename added when the user downloads the image then answer of @fuyushimoya is better for you. You need to add an `<a>` tag with a `download` attribute. Just be careful. `Download` attribute has some compatibility issues, see [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Comment: I tried the code of @fuyushimoya but I couldn't get it working. Your code works better for appending to a div within the same page load.

Comment: I used this to append the canvas dataurl to a div and then hide the output div.
$("#qrcodediv").append('<img width="500" height="325" src="'+img+'"/>');
document.getElementById("output").style.display = "none"

Comment: So it's just the issue of when you right click and save the image, it has the dataurl as the filename (reverts to untitled), and would prefer it to be another name.

Comment: How to handle with " render: 'canvas',mode: 4,image: $('#logo')[0] ", I got an error and no idea to fix it: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.  Pls advise with thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("output");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

would get executed earlier than `jQuery('#output').qrcode("http://");`, `domready` only starts when every element on the page is accessible, and `scripts` are executed on load. So they should be put into that `domready` callback too.

Another issues is jquery.qrcode creates a `canvas` under target, so `var canvas = document.getElementById("output");` would find the `div`, not the canvas, you can use `document.querySelector("#output canvas");` to get it.

And if you just want a image to be downloadable, set an event handler, then when it's triggered, create an `<a>` and set `href` to the canvas.toDataURL, `download` to the filename you want, then simulate a click.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.qrcode/1.0/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
<script>
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#output').qrcode("http://");
   
  // the lib generate a canvas under target, you should get that canvas, not #output
  // And put the code here would ensure that you can get the canvas, and canvas has the image.
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#output canvas");
  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  $(canvas).on('click', function() {
    // Create an anchor, and set its href and download.
    var dl = document.createElement('a');
    dl.setAttribute('href', img);
    dl.setAttribute('download', 'qrcode.png');
    // simulate a click will start download the image, and name is qrcode.png.
    dl.click();
  });
   
  // Note this will overwrite any current content.
  // document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
})

</script>
```